# Using a method on a React class from a separate component

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

On the home page of my site, you can click a menu button that triggers a method which toggles a menu. This changes the state from `menuOpen` from `false` to `true`.

On a different page, I click a 'back' button, and it should go to the home route, but open this menu when the page has loaded rather than when I click. Currently all I have is:

```
handleBack(){
   App.navigate('/');
}
```

Can I `import` the component and call its method? Or can I set up a new React Router route that somehow executes the state change? Or is there another way around it?

Comment: Setup working js fiddle. Then, we might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redux would help, but since I'm guessing you're not using that OR you don't want to refactor your entire application to set this one boolean, I'd recommend using a higher order component.

So for example, you'd define a higher-order component (think superclass) like this:

```
export function menuToggler(ComposedComponent) {

    return class extends React.Component {
        toggleMenuBoolean() {
            // code here
        },
        render() {
            return <ComposedComponent toggleMenuBoolean={toggleMenuBoolean} {...this.props} />
        }
    };
}
```

Then, in your regular component, you simply wrap it with the higher order component.  So if previously, you were using ES6 and exporting your component like this:

```
export default MyComponent;
```

It would then become:

```
export default menuToggler(MyComponent);
```

From there, you can invoke this `toggleMenuBoolean` function from any component that is wrapped by your higher order component by simply calling it on props:

`this.props.toggleMenuBoolean(false)`, etc.

More reading here:

https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750#.sh6m9c9ct

Answer (score 1):

If you want that scenario, pass the state value to the parent component which is a 'smart component' manages dumb componenets. Or you can use 'flux' / 'redux'.